# How to sync digital ocean spaces from one account to another

Tags: digital-ocean, s3cmd

I have two digital ocean accounts.

- Account A

  - space A
- Account B

  - space B

I am using version s3cmd `2.02`.

I have to transfer all the files from `space A` to `space B`. I have read the [documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/resources/s3cmd-usage/) on its usage but this documentaion doesn't cover my use case.

---

I want to sync these two spaces where `A` is the source and `B` is the destination.

I have tried the following :

1. I created a conf file `~/.s3conf` with key and secret from account A.
2. I renamed it to `~/.s3conf-first`
3. I created a conf file again with the key and secret from account B.
4. I then list spaces from both conf file. running.

   1. `s3cmd ls -c ~/.s3cfg-first` > `2021-06-08 09:23  s3://A`
   2. `s3cmd ls` > `2021-06-08 09:23  s3://B`
5. Now I want to sync so I run : `s3cmd sync s3://A -c ~/.s3cfg-first s3://B` it is returning

```bsh
ERROR: S3 error: 403 (AccessDenied)
```

---

How can I use two conf file in a single command to syn data between two different spaces created in two different accounts ( with two diff keys ) ?

Comment: Just reading over the [command line options](https://s3tools.org/usage) linked in the Digital Ocean guide, the official form for `sync` seems to be `s3cmd sync LOCAL_DIR s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX] or s3://BUCKET[/PREFIX] LOCAL_DIR`. I haven't used this tool myself but `LOCAL_DIR` would seem to perhaps imply it isn't an S3 bucket (i.e. you might need to sync files from `A` to an intermediary running `s3cmd` then from the intermediary back to `B` in two separate steps).

Comment: Yes, I am using a droplet and copying files there, will transfer there to destination